# Why does b(string) and bytes(string, ‘utf-8’) give different results in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
byte_1 = b'\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8'
byte_2 = bytes('\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8', 'utf-8')
byte_3 = ('\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8').encode()
```

Here byte_1 == byte_2 is False but byte_2 == byte_3 is True. Can someone help me understand why is that the case?

Comment: 1 is already a byte string. 2 and 3 are Unicode strings being encoded to byte strings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thank you. how do I convert 2 or 3 to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`byte_1` is already a byte string. `byte_2` and `byte_3` are Unicode strings being encoded to byte strings.

`'\xc0'` is an escape code representing a Unicode code point, U+00C0.
`b'\xc0'` is an escape code representing a byte value of 0xC0.

In UTF-8, Unicode code points above U+007F are encoded in two or more bytes, so `'\xc0'.encode()` returns the two bytes `b'\xc3\x80'`.

If you want to get equivalent strings, use the `latin1` codec.  The Latin-1 (a.k.a ISO-8859-1) character set occupies the first 256 code points of the Unicode standard, and therefore maps 1:1 from code points < U+0100 to bytes.  Example:

```py
byte_1 = b'\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8'
byte_2 = bytes('\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8', 'latin1')
byte_3 = ('\xc0*\xael<\x9e\xcf\x81\xa2\xd8\xb5\xe3\x1d\xe1\xaa8').encode('latin1')

print(byte_1 == byte_2)
print(byte_1 == byte_3)
print(byte_2 == byte_3)
```

```
True
True
True
```

Recommended reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html)

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because as pointed out by @mark, `byte_1`is a byte string. When you use the `bytes()` method for `byte_2`, you actually specified the encodings as unicode or utf-8. If you would have chose rather different encoding like ISO-8859-1 for `byte_2`, then `byte_2` and `byte_3` would not be the same. Since the `encode()` method has default encoding of utf-8, it results true for `byte_2==byte_3`

Comment: Thank you. What should be the string `my_string` so that I could convert that to be equal to `byte_1`?

Comment: @3123 you can try using the `chardet` module to detect the encoding of `byte_1`

Comment: thanks. using `chardet` i found that the encoding of `byte_1` is `windows-1252`. However, when I do `my_bytes.decode('windows-1252’)`, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 7: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @3123 that is because byte sequence 0x81 in unicode has no equivalent char. in win1252 encoding